# Reset time on daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, daterangepicker

We are using the [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) in our project with time picker enabled and we want to reset the time when someone selects a date range.

So I have an initial selection like this with date and time range:
[image]

And now when the user selects a new date range I want the time range to be reset back to the start of the selected day (12:00 pm) and to the end of the selected date (11:59 am):
[image]

Is there some way to achieve that without modifying the source code?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you do it, but the way with jQuery will look like that. Basically, we listened to `apply.daterangepicker` and `cancel.daterangepicker` and handle it. Call `prepareDateRangeControl` will init all the date range picker. Noted that it is the way we did it on our ASP.NET MVC project as server-side rendering and jQuery present to touch some UI element after the page was rendered only.

```
function prepareDateRangeControl() {
    function adjustWidth(control) {
        control.attr('size', control.val().length);
    }

    $(".form-control.daterange").each(function () {

        $(this).daterangepicker({
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            applyClass: "btn-primary",
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,

            format: $(this).data("format"),
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: "Clear",
                format: $(this).data("format")
            },
            ranges: {
                "Today": [moment().startOf("day"), moment().endOf("day")],
                "Yesterday": [moment().subtract(1, "days").startOf("day"), moment().subtract(1, "days").endOf("day")],
                "Last 7 Days": [moment().subtract(6, "days").startOf("day"), moment().endOf("day")],
                "Last 30 Days": [moment().subtract(29, "days").startOf("day"), moment().endOf("day")],
                "This Month": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().endOf("month")]
            }
        });

        adjustWidth($(this));
    });

    $(".form-control.daterange").on("apply.daterangepicker", function (event, picker) {

        if (picker.startDate.hour() === 0 && picker.startDate.minute() === 0) {
            if (picker.endDate.hour() === 0 && picker.endDate.minute() === 0) {

                picker.endDate.hour("23");
                picker.endDate.minute("59");
            }
        }

        var format = $(this).data("format");
        var text = picker.startDate.format(format) + " - " + picker.endDate.format(format);
        picker.element.val(text);
        adjustWidth($(this));
    });

    $(".form-control.daterange").on("cancel.daterangepicker", function (event, picker) {
        picker.element.val("");
        adjustWidth($(this));
    });
}
```

For the Angular project, we are also using [ng2-daterangepicker](https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker) but this use case we don't need to handle the time picker as your requirement. I hope the idea will be the same as the above code because it also encapsulates and provides the same event as the original library.

Answer (score -1):

I ' m using this in angular 6 project

@ViewChild(datePick) private picker: datePick;

//for reset the default date
this.datePick = null;

Is this working for you? its working for me